# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mkdirs'

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

While creating a nested directory in Python 3.6 received following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mkdirs'
```

Sample code:

```
def create_sample_data():
    os.mkdirs("/tmp/lambdadir/ProjectTemp/mynewtest")
    f=open("/tmp/lambdadir/ProjectTemp/mynewtest/my_copy.txt","w+")
    f.write("This is inside a directory")
    f.close()
```

Please help.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no `os.mkdirs`.  Perhaps you meant [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) or [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) instead?

Comment: *ae*, that's what I needed :)

Answer (score 7):

After googling a bit, found that, its a Python version issue.

I changed code from *os.mkdirs()* to ***os.makedirs()*** and it worked.

Details: [os module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.makedirs)

Credits: 
[buttscicles - Reddit](http://%20https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/y64ym/attributeerror_module_object_has_no_attribute/)

Comment: Since your using 3.6, consider using [path.mkdir(parents=True)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) and [path.write_text('this is inside a directory')](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.write_text). In general, I've found pathlib much easier to use for any kind of filesystem manipulation

Comment: @Ben apart from being more explicit, is there any functional benefit?

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax, it's much easier code to write. The four lines in the function become two lines with pathlib - probably wouldn't even put that in a function. Check out pathlib the next time you deal with paths/files/folders. I personally guarantee (for what that's worth lol) that you'll like it.

Answer (score 1):

In 3.10  when I tried it I faced the same. seems it's not available,
so I used below code.

```
# The folder should not exist or else will throw FileExistsError
os.mkdir('Parent-folder')
# The parent folder is should be created before , or else throws FileNotFoundError:
os.mkdir('Parent-folder/SubFolder')
```